# strong induction with fibonacci sequence

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

The Fibonacci numbers {Fn} are defined by the recurrence:

F1 =1
F2 =1
Fn =Fn−1+Fn−2 for n≥3.

Prove: 2|Fn if and only if 3|Fn.

So would I need to be thinking of using strong induction to show this? My thinking is, looking at the sequence: 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21... now if we are considering 2 dividing into one of these numbers, then it would need to be even for one thing, as well as divisible by 3.  I do see that, if dividing by 3, we have the possible remainders: 0,1 or 2 which looks helpful... maybe... not sure.  I'm pretty lost on how to go about working on this one.  Any help here would be awesome.

Comment: This is obviously false: Both $8$ and $21$ are counterexamples in the first few terms you wrote....

Comment: but aren't we only looking at one specific number in the sequence?

Comment: You want $2\mid F_n$ if and only if $3\mid n$.

Comment: Again, Prove: 2|Fn if and only if 3|Fn not 3|n.

Comment: @billyredface88 The statement it seems you're trying to prove is for all $n$, not just a specific one - hence, a single counterexample is enough to show it's false. There are many counterexamples here. I think that André Nicolas has likely suggested the correct modification of your question.

Comment: Ok so... let n=3.  Then: ->: 2|F_2+F_1 which 2|1+1 and is true.  assuming that n=3, then 3|1+1 and yeah... that won't work.  So, then would I just repeat this to go in the other direction of the statement?

Comment: Well after going taking care of both directions, which, I guess you still have to do since this is bi-conditional, it definitely is false as I ended up having 2=3c for some c in the naturals, or that (using contrapositive) 3 does not divide 2 implies 2 does not divide 2 which is also false.

Comment: Maybe $2|F_{F_n}$ iff $3|F_n$?

Comment: So since this doesn't work to at least establish a base case (where n=3), then the whole thing just stops here?  Still confused.